# Android always shows **Emergency Calls Only**

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have an Android 5.1 phone and since about 2-3 days, my phone always shows **Emergency Calls Only** in the Notification area:

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]

I know that this is not an issue, it doesn't bother me and my device works normally, I am just curious why its happening.

Comment: It's either "BSNL Mobile's" fault or you just have a faulty SIM card. Try removing the SIM card while the device is on (so Android realizes the change) and reseating it.

Comment: Could it be your SIM is data only? Then it doesn't allow for "normal calls", and you can do "emergency calls only". Which is why it says so. Though that wouldn't explain why it happens only since 2-3 days. Was it different before? Have you tried rebooting the device? Can you, despite of the message, make and receive normal calls?

Comment: Yeah i can make and receive calls and my sim is not data only and I have tried rebooting..